# Error invoking API returning boolean ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, jackson-databind

I have a spring project where I have the following API impl in the controller:

```
   public ResponseEntity<Boolean> testApi(
                @ApiParam @RequestParam(value = "xxx", required = false) String name) {
            boolean abc = false;  // or true
            return new ResponseEntity<>(abc, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

the API returns the result fine when invoked via postman. However, in my unit test, where I call it as:

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new 
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
restTemplate.getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
ResponseEntity<Boolean> xyz = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Boolean.class);
```

I  get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Boolean] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Boolean` out of START_OBJECT token
```

Note- My restTemplate is a `org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;`

and Autowired as:

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
```

I am seeing this problem only when invoking API returning boolean. For other APIs returning objects, it works fine

Comment: can you show how are you creating resttemplate object?, may be try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656530/httpmessageconverter-exception-restclientexception-could-not-write-request-n/54751169#54751169

Comment: I updated my question with how restTemplate is created and how I tried what you suggested in your link but I get same error

Comment: may be try `StringHttpMessageConverter` instead of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`